Issuing Connection to AWS RDS Server SQL Database: Server Remote Connection: The server was not found or accessible: TCP Provider. Error 0
My coworker and I, are connection to RDS SQL Server using SSMS. He is currently able to connection without issue. However I am having issues: I am getting the network related instance error:

The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify the instance name is correct. TCP Provider error 0 (see screenshot).

He has walked me through Configuration Manager and my TCP/IP is Enabled (see screen shot), and I restarted my instance on my machine of SQL Server. He sent the exact URI for the connection with the port and still I get this error. Any assistance or insight would be greatly appreciated.
[Error Message][1]
[TCP/IP Enabled][2]
[Service is running][3]


Have you checked that your public IP address is permitted access through the service's AWS security groups? Are you using a version of SSMS that can actually connect to the version of SQL Server at AWS? (Not all versions are compatible among each other.)
